# Why are the results only returning when not using 'async' module?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous, closures

The technologies I am using are Node.js, express and MongoDB.

I have a method called 'getAllRecipes' that queries the database for all recipes - this works fine.

In the 'getAllRecipes' callback method, I then loop each entry / recipe to get it's notes and comments. The tasks inside the loop are placed inside of a closure in order to imitate 'let' otherwise every recipeID will be the same.

Now I add further calls to an array to use in conjunction with 'async.series'.
First of all I make the call to 'getRecipeNotes', and when this returns I make a call to 'getRecipeComments' in the 'getRecipeNotes' callback method.

The final output shows something along the following:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "56d070ac7c3965e85d3ebd38",
    "userID": "56cf383a1f8303082484f35f",
    "name": "Chocolate cake",
    "instructions": "Add mixture to bowl, and then mix",
    "dateTimeSubmitted": "2016-02-26T15:35:08.868Z",
    "tags": "cooking, cake, chocolate",
    "active": 1,
    "notes": [],
    "comments": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "56d070ac7c3965e85d3ebd3a",
    "name": "num1",
    "quantity": "5",
    "notes": [],
    "comments": []
  }, ...]
```

Every single 'notes' and every single 'comments' are empty arrays.

I have checked the comments collection and there is an entry against recipeID : "56d070ac7c3965e85d3ebd38".

If I modify the 'getRecipeComments' method to return all comments for each recipe, then all are returned.

Also, If I keep the query using recipeID and make a call outside of the getAllRecipes method with recipeID : "56d070ac7c3965e85d3ebd38", then it also returns the data fine.. just not using the getAllRecipes method.

getAllRecipes:

```
function getAllRecipes( db, callback )
{
    //query( db, {}, 'recipes', callback );
    query( db, {}, 'recipes', function( err, recipeData )
    {
        tempArray = recipeData.slice();

        if( err || !tempArray.length )
            callback( err );
        else
        {
            var taskArr = [];

            for( var i=0; i < tempArray.length; i++ )
            {   
                (function()
                {
                    var tID = tempArray[ i ]._id;
                    taskArr.push( function( iCallback )
                    { 
                        getRecipeNotes( db, tID, function( err2, noteData )
                        { 
                            getRecipeComments( db, tID, function( err3, commentData )
                            {
                                if( err2 )
                                {
                                    iCallback( err2 );
                                    return;
                                }   

                                if( err3 )
                                {
                                    iCallback( err3 );                        
                                    return;
                                }

                                for( var j=0; j < tempArray.length; j++ )
                                {
                                    if( tempArray[ j ]._id === tID )
                                    {
                                        tempArray[ j ].notes                = noteData;
                                        tempArray[ j ].comments             = commentData;
                                    }
                                }

                                iCallback();
                            });
                        });
                    });
                })();
            }

            async.series( taskArr, function( err )
            {
                callback( err, tempArray );

            } );
        }
    });
}
```

getRecipeComments:

```
function getRecipeComments( db, recipeID, callback )
{
    query( db, { recipeID : recipeID }, 'comments', callback );
}
```

query:

```
function query( db, query, strColl, callback )
{
    var coll = db.get( strColl );

    coll.find( query, function( err, doc )
   {    
      if( err )
        console.log( err );

      callback( err, doc );
   });
}
```

I also separated the calls to 'getRecipeNotes' and 'getRecipeComments' to two seperate tasks, but the result is the same.

Can you see why the notes or comments are refusing to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. It seemed to be a type error on the call to querying the database.

i just needed to do a simple:

```
recipeID = recipeID.toString();
```

before the query